# Does `FIND PATH` clause support `WHERE` in NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

The `FIND PATH` clause is useful in graph traversing. For example

```
FIND SHORTEST PATH FROM "player102" TO "team204" OVER * YIELD path AS p;
```

But the filter condition is commonly used in traversing, I.e, the `WEHER` clause.

The manual didn't give any examples or syntax about how to write a `WHERE` clause. Some statements  work and some won't

```
FIND ALL PATH FROM "player100" TO "team204" OVER * WHERE follow.degree is EMPTY or follow.degree >=0 YIELD path AS p;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| p                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| <("player100")-[:serve@0 {}]->("team204")>                                   |
| <("player100")-[:follow@0 {}]->("player125")-[:serve@0 {}]->("team204")>     |
| <("player100")-[:follow@0 {}]->("player101")-[:serve@0 {}]->("team204")>     |
|...                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
FIND ALL PATH FROM "player100" TO "team204" OVER * where player.age is EMPTY or follow.degree >=0
--- a syntax error occurs.
```

Does it support `WHERE`, and how to write `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

`FIND PATH` only supports filtering properties of edges with `WHERE` clauses, such as `WHERE follow.degree is EMPTY or follow.degree >=0`.

Filtering properties of vertices is not supported currently by [version 3.3.0](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/).

Comment: Do you have links to official documentation or release notes to back up your statement? If you can find them, please [edit] to add them to your answer.